# RadGridview Bind resets filtering and column widths

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

When a user manually resizes the column width or add filters to a RadGridview or any other change and then binds, the RadGridview is reset to defaults i.e no filter and columns widths are as when the application was first started. Can I stop this from happening ?

```
// Bind list to gridview
this.radGridViewFiles.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = null));
this.radGridViewFiles.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Concat(MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(i => i.sItemRequestStatus == "Add").ToList())));
```

Answer (score 2):

The width and the filters will be kept for the columns that still exist i.e. if you have a column with name "Column1" and when you rebind the grid you still have this column, its width and filter will be kept. Still, if you don't have such column, this data is and should be lost.

Also, RadGridView offers save/load layout functionality, which you can use to save the state of the grid and restore it at a later moment. More information about this is available here: [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-save-and-load-layout-overview.html)